# a sendasync mail function, do you see any potential memory leak?

Tags: vb.net, smtp

I have that code running into a windows service and the service seem to have a memory leak, something is wrong for sure.

After looking at the whole code, I think it might be inside one of these function but I cannot seem to find where it could be.

Anyone could take a look and could let me know if something is wrong?

thanks for any kind of help.

```
Public Function sendEmail(Optional ByVal msg As String = "") As Boolean
    Dim mailSent As Boolean = False
    Dim mail As Net.Mail.MailMessage = Nothing
    Dim smtp As Net.Mail.SmtpClient = Nothing

    Try
        mail = New Net.Mail.MailMessage
        mail.From = New Net.Mail.MailAddress("myemail@myaddress.com")
        mail.Priority = Net.Mail.MailPriority.High
        mail.To.Add("1@1.1")
        mail.To.Add("2@1.1")
        mail.To.Add("3@1.1")
        mail.Subject = "test"
        mail.Body = msg
        Dim stream As IO.MemoryStream = createReport(Of IO.MemoryStream)()
        mail.Attachments.Add(New Net.Mail.Attachment(stream, "Report.html", "text/html"))

        smtp = New Net.Mail.SmtpClient("my.smtp.server")
        AddHandler smtp.SendCompleted, AddressOf SendCompletedCallback
        smtp.SendAsync(mail, mail)
        mailSent = True
    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.Print(ex.Message)
    End Try

    If mail IsNot Nothing Then
        mail = Nothing
    End If

    If smtp IsNot Nothing Then
        smtp = Nothing
    End If

    Return mailSent
End Function

Private Sub SendCompletedCallback(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs)

    Try
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim mail As Net.Mail.MailMessage = CType(e.UserState, Net.Mail.MailMessage)
        If e.Cancelled Then
            Throw New Exception("Send mail got cancelled")
        ElseIf e.Error IsNot Nothing Then
            Throw e.Error
        End If
        For i = (mail.Attachments.Count - 1) To 0 Step -1
            mail.Attachments(i).Dispose()
        Next
        mail.Dispose()
        RemoveHandler CType(sender, Net.Mail.SmtpClient).SendCompleted, AddressOf SendCompletedCallback
    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.Print(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub


Public Function createReport(Of dataType)() As dataType
    Dim result As Object = Nothing

    Dim ds As DataSet = Nothing
    Dim xmlDoc As Xml.XmlDocument = Nothing
    Dim xslTran As Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform = Nothing

    Try
        Dim i As Integer


        ds = New dsEventLog ''dataset
        If IO.File.Exists("c:\myxmlfile") Then
            ds.Tables(0).ReadXml("c:\myxmlfile")
            For i = ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
                If CDate(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("LocalTime")) < Now.AddDays(-5) Then
                    ds.Tables(0).Rows.RemoveAt(i)
                End If
            Next
        End If

        xmlDoc = New Xml.XmlDataDocument(ds)
        xslTran = New Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform
        xslTran.Load("c:\myxslfile")

        If GetType(dataType) Is GetType(String) Then
            'doesn't matter
        ElseIf GetType(dataType) Is GetType(IO.MemoryStream) Then
            Dim stream = New IO.MemoryStream
            Dim sw As IO.StreamWriter = New IO.StreamWriter(stream)
            xslTran.Transform(xmlDoc, Nothing, sw)
            stream.Position = 0

            result = stream

            sw = Nothing
            stream = Nothing
        Else
            Throw New Exception("Incorrect ""Of dataType"" used!")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.Print(ex.Message)
    End Try

    If ds IsNot Nothing Then
        ds.Dispose()
    End If
    ds = Nothing

    xslTran = Nothing
    xmlDoc = Nothing

    Return CType(result, dataType)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should dispose of the memory stream, by calling the Dispose method. You should also dispose of objects of any class that implements IDisposable to release unmanaged memory.

Also, you don't have to set variables to Nothing. This can actually keep objects in memory longer than they have to.

**Edit:**

If I'm not mistaken the attachments are disposed but not the stream itself...

Also if you look at the [example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx), the mail message is disposed in the main code, not in the callback.

Other problem: If the mail cannot be sent, no Dispose is called. If there is an exception, you don't call dispose either. You should put your Dispose calls in finally blocks so that unmanaged resources are disposed in all cases. Or even better, use [Using blocks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) when you can.

Comment: the stream should be disposed in SendCompletedCallback, the loop with the mail attachments